# Map package layers' sources are broken

Tags: arcgis-desktop, map-package

I'm making a map package to use it later in a WPF application, I shared the layers as a map package and there is no problem but when I tried to open the map package file again I found that all the layers have the red exclamation mark which means that the link to the data is broken, I fixed it and set the data source then  re shared again but the problem persist.

### Here are the pics of the situation:

First before sharing the map package everything is good
[image: First before sharing the map package everything is good]

Opening the map package file I found the link is broken
[image: Opening the map package file I found the link is broken]

Here when I tried to share it again before fixing the data source to see what error will result
[image: Here when I tried to share it again before fixing the data source to see what error will result]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you just need to ensure that you are using relative paths in the map document that you package.

From the [Setting map document properties](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-arcmap/setting-map-document-properties.htm) help:

> You can define how path references are maintained in your document by
>   checking or unchecking **Store relative pathnames to data source**. If
>   this box is checked, paths are stored as incomplete paths that are
>   relative to the current location of this document on disk. Using
>   relative paths makes the map document more easily portable because
>   ArcGIS will resolve the paths to the document's data sources relative
>   to the document's current location in the file system rather than by
>   full paths that include a drive letter or machine name.
>
> Using relative paths doesn't mean that the layers in your document
>   will never need repairing. Even with relative paths, it is still
>   possible for a document to be unable to find its data sources if the
>   document or the data sources are moved to a different location
>   relative to each other, such as to a different part of the folder
>   hierarchy or to a different disk.

Comment: Well that worked when I unchecked the Reference data Option in the "Share as Map package dialog".
But also I noticed a strange thing when I tried to re share it but in another location with everything the same as my first trial it worked with no problems, what I suspect was the problem is that the first path contains **Arabic characters** unlike the other path.